# Raster data analysis

Tags: python, numpy, loops, raster

I have converted the raster file into a NumPy array. since the data set in the NumPy array is the elevations, I want to calculate the elevation difference greater than 100 m and it should be within a 1000m radius. the resolution of the cell is 30mx30m.

Can someone suggest if I should use a loop or it can be done another way out? Please help.

Comment: If I understand you, you want to obtain all disks of radius 1000 m that contain two pixels with a difference exceeding 100 (m). This can be done using a so-called morphological gradient (dilation minus erosion) with a structuring element that is a digital disk of radius 33 (= 990 m), followed by thresholding. You can do that directly in OpenCV. This gives you all disk centers. You can dilate again to obtain all disk areas.

Comment: thanks for the response, actually i want to use raster data to identify potential pump storage plant site , with upper and lower reservior. The cells that fullfill the criteria will be upper and lower reservior ie the difference should be more that 100m and it should be within 1000m radius.

Comment: Why do you repeat this ?

Comment: thanks let me go through it and will get back to you.

Comment: hi, can you elaborate a bit , how exactly should i approach , as i am struggling a bit to locate a disk from a rater or a numpy array file. please excuse me as i am a bit new to & am still learning. request for help.Thanks

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga4ff0f3318642c4f469d0e11f242f3b6c